# Weird error message on the mysqli_query while Insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dreamweaver, sql-insert

I try to insert record into  mysql database

```
INSERT INTO tbl_messages
(msgTitle,msgMessage,msgDateScheduled,fkmsgAppId,msgImage,msgAction,fkmsgSerial) 
values
('essfd','fgf','2014-03-30T00:12','2','test.jpg','none','11111');
```

But although the statement is correct, I keep getting this error:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '
>       ' at line 1

If I copy and paste this insert in mysql client , it inserts the record without error.

I cant figure out where is the problem.
Can anyone help me?

My code is this:

ok, you are right ,i have to show the code.

i work this project in dreamweaver.
actually i read 2 arrays and i create insert statements and i insert them in db.

```
//include database file
include("dbconn.php");
//make the db connection
$myConn = new DB_Class("DB","user","password");

//initialize the string that will keep the sq   
$sqlString ="";

//outer  loop
foreach($arrayRecipients as $key2 => $row2){

    $sqlString ="INSERT INTO tbl_messages (msgTitle,msgMessage,msgDateScheduled,fkmsgAppId,msgImage,msgAction,fkmsgSerial) values (";

    //inner loop
    foreach($arrayValues as $key1 => $row1){

        $sqlString .= "'".$arrayValues[$key1]."',";
        }//end for


          //the last 3 values are fixed for now 
    $sqlString .= "'test.jpg','none','11111');</br>";

         //i call the insert function
    $myConn->insUpdRecordTest($sqlString);

        //initialize sqlstirng for the next loop
    $sqlString = "";
    }//end for
```

on the dbconn.php the code is :

```
 CLASS DB_Class {

 VAR $db;
function DB_Class($dbname, $username, $password) {

       $this->db = mysqli_connect ('server', $username, $password)
       or DIE ("Unable to connect to Database Server");
        mysqli_select_db( $this->db,$dbname) or DIE ("Could not select database");

 }

 function query($sql) {

        $result = mysqli_query ($this->db,$sql) or DIE ("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($this->db));
        return $result;

 }

  ///////////////////////////
 function insUpdRecordTest($sql){
     $result = $this->query($sql);

    return  $result;

 }
 }
```

Comment: show us ur php code and ur table structure

Comment: The query appears to be fine, It might be the `mysqli_query()` function which has a bad qoute

Comment: Table structure is not needed with this error, you would get a 'column/table doesnt exist' error

Comment: Remove the two ** at the end ?

Comment: Try replacing all single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: Show your table structure I presume the values given in the query are inconsistent with the datatypes of the table.

Comment: If the error happens only in PHP, and you don't show your PHP code, it will be hard to help.

Comment: i updated my code.you can see it above.

Comment: Thank you guys, i funally found the 'ghost' error. It hides on this line :  //the last 3 values are fixed for now 
    $sqlString .= "'test.jpg','none','11111');</br>";   i should delete the </br>  !!!